Using SignalR in a RAZOR OnPost method to update the client page with status
In my RAZOR web app I want to update the client page with the progress as an OnPost method executes in the server. I have seen the example using SignalR to blast a message to all the clients and have it working fine for me. But I only want to send messages to the caller who initiated the OnPost, not all clients. I cannot figure out how to modify it to message just one client.
Can anyone point me to a link or an example somewhere on the web or in github? I see quite a few MVC and Blazor examples but I have learned those technologies don't always translate to RAZOR. Plus I need example code in an OnPost which may be triggered by a form submission or a javascript fetch (AJAX).

I found the answer from Rena had the kind of sample I was looking for:
update progress bar from razor server
